# Find least frequently occurring character in a column in dataframe

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, stringr

I am working with planes dataset from nycflights13 package. I want to find the Find the least frequently occurring character From tailnum column in the planes dataset.

I tried using str_split & boundary() but did not know how to proceed with that

```
 library(tidyverse)
 library(nycflights13)
 planes<- nycflights13::planes

 strsplit(word(planes$tailnum),boundary("character"))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

split every word into characters, count them using `table`, `sort` and select the 1st value.

```
sort(table(unlist(strsplit(planes$tailnum, ''))))[1]

#G 
#9
```

Or using `tidyverse` :

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

planes %>%
  separate_rows(tailnum, sep = '') %>%
  filter(tailnum != '') %>%
  count(tailnum) %>%
  slice_min(n, n = 1)

#  tailnum     n
#  <chr>   <int>
#1 G           9
```

Comment: Thanks, this is perfect if the same was least occurring word, how would we have gone about that

Comment: For the word you can split on whitespace. Something like this - `sort(table(unlist(strsplit(planes$tailnum, ' '))))[1]`

Comment: Done, I have done all in the past, somehow missed this., appreciate the tidy way to answer as well